# Create subtasks through workflow

Tags: workflow

I'm trying to have it set up so that when an item is created in a `Project List` (just a regular list) there are several tasks, which I know need to be completed, initiated in by `Task List`. I have the workflow set up to see when a new item is added to my `Project List` and I can create all the appropriate tasks. 
[image]

but what I'm not able to do is make subtasks.

I can associate tasks as predecessors but on a Gantt chart it doesn't really convey what I want it to. I want it to look like this in the end

[image]

Is there a way to do this via a workflow?

I'm using SP 2013